# How do I change the starting value of my autoincremental code

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to increment a cell after printing but I don't know how to change the starting value. Right now it starts at 1 but this form was being  used manually for a long time so I need it to start around 105,300

I tried changing the value of the cell (G9) in the line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = "" & I
```

but it always reset. For example I print 3 copies and sequence works. I print 5 more but it reverted back to 105290 as a starting point.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim xCount As Variant
Dim xScreen As Boolean
Dim I As Long
On Error Resume Next
LInput:
xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:")
If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation
GoTo LInput
Else
xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For I = 1 To xCount
ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = "" & I
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("G9").UpdateContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
End If
End Sub
```

I'm looking for this to continually update the cell so the user doesn't have to do this manually.

Comment: I might be mistaken, not understanding your question properly, but would `ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value & I` fix it for you? Sidenote, you should avoid `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @JvdV, I tried using that but (starting at number 105290) it resulted in 10529012345. I can try to explain more clearly, this cell value is currently 105290. I need to it to update continuously as the customer service people print copies. I need the value to go 105290,105291,105292...etc. without them having to change anything manually

Comment: So instead of & you can use +

Comment: Could I replace ActiveSheet with the name of the worksheet?

Comment: Yes: `Worksheet("Sheet name here").`

Comment: @JvdV, Thank you. Changing it to + 1 instead of & I made it work.